# Android webview will only play some videos not the others

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I am trying to play videos on  android webview. Some of the videos play well and some of them are scrambled(audio works but the video is a bunch of lines. Like you are searching for a TV channel)
And the ones that play , have the wrong colors(every one has a blue face). has anyone come across a similar problem?

```
WebView ourBrow; 
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ourBrow =(WebView) findViewById(R.id.wvBrowser);
    ourBrow.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    ourBrow.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
    ourBrow.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    ourBrow.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    ourBrow.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    ourBrow.setWebViewClient(new ourViewClient());}




    public class ourViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView v, String url){

    v.loadUrl(url);
    return true;

}
```

Comment: Could we see some code?

Comment: I posted the code . I also need to mention that I have hardware accelerated turned on.

Comment: I also observed this, but when I seeked forward the video...

Comment: It might have something to do with the MediaEngine on your device. Did you have the chance to test it using another device? Generally speaking, when you observe video or audio, that means the native MediaEngine has take over the work (playback) from WebView.